# JSTL change key of LinkedHashmap

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap, jstl, iteration

I have a linkedHashmap in JSP.

I want to change its keys on some condition, keeping values intact.
How to do it?

```
  <c:forEach var="loop" items="${Courses}"
                varStatus="pLoop">

    <c:set var="pKey" value="${pKey+1}"/> <!-- value that needs to be set as new key -->

    <fmt:parseNumber var="tempKey" integerOnly="true" 
                   type="number" value="${loop.key}" />

    <!--Normally key values are set like this in hashmap in jstl --> 

    <c:set target="${Courses}" property="${pKey}" value="something"/>

    <!-- but I want to keep value intact, want to change only key -->                       
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a map you don't change the key. You put the new key with same value and remove the old key.

Comment: How to remove in jstl, I have done it in java so many times but not sure how to do it with jstl.

Comment: Not sure you can remove in JSTL but you can set value of old key to `null`.

Comment: like this: <c:set var="${Courses[oldkey]}" value="null"/> ?? Pardon my ignorance but I am new to jstl.

Comment: I would have done it the same way you already did : `<c:set target="${Courses}" property="key" value="${null}"/>`